# How to get Hierarchy Node levels of a Telerik treeview 

Tags: c#, javascript, xml, telerik

Hi I am populating an dynamic **XML file into telerik treeview** as **hierarchy tree view** as below.

```
Modules //root node

* Organization //Parent node

    *Policy  //Child of Organization

    *Transports

* Employess   

    *Salary

* Rewards

    *Winners
```

When i am going to select **Modules-> Organization -> Policy** , I want to get this hierarchy in my client event but Now I am getting the last node value only as "**Policy**". I want to get the full path of this herarchy.

And my client event code is:

```
    function onSelect(e) {
    debugger;
    var tv = $('#HierarchyView').data('tTreeView');
    var file = tv.getItemValue(e.item); // Here I am getting the last node name as "Policy", I want to get it as Modules-> Organization -> Policy 
    var nodeElement = e.item;
    }
```

Can anyone please tell me the way to get that **Hierarchy**? Its Urgent.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

[Telerkik Documentation for Node Path with javascript](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/treeview-client-nodes-full-path.html)

regards